# Tkinter Treeview issue when inserting rows with tags

Tags: tkinter, insert, tags, treeview

I have just switched from python 3.6 to python 3.7. I have a function which inserts rows in a Treeview tree with tags. The tags are used for giving a foreground color and a background color to the rows inserted to the tree. My code was working ok when I was using python 3.6. Once I switched to 3.7 the rows inserted were not given a background or foreground color but where only given a white background and a black foreground color.

There doesn't seem to be a syntax change in tkinter.ttk from python 3.6 to 3.7 regarding tag configuration or tree insert.

```
tree.tag_configure('MATCHED', foreground='dark green', background='gray98')
tree.tag_configure('UNMATCHED', foreground='red2', background='gray98')

if match_status== '1':
    tree.insert('', 'end', text=df_row, values=my_value, tag='MATCHED')
elif match_status == '0':
    tree.insert('', 'end', text=df_row, values=my_value, tag='UNMATCHED')`
```

It is expected that when the rows are inserted to the tree to be given the correct background and foreground color.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code worked for me when I used a different background color. As an experiment, what happens when you change `background` to `'red'`? It would also help if you created a working [mcve]. It shouldn't take but a dozen lines or so. That would rule out that some other code is causing the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like the issue was caused by a newer version of tkinter, not a newer version of Python. This was reported in https://bugs.python.org/issue36468 and https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/info/509cafafae

Here is a proposed solution. It should be both backward and forward compatible:

```
def fixed_map(option):
    # Fix for setting text colour for Tkinter 8.6.9
    # From: https://core.tcl.tk/tk/info/509cafafae
    #
    # Returns the style map for 'option' with any styles starting with
    # ('!disabled', '!selected', ...) filtered out.

    # style.map() returns an empty list for missing options, so this
    # should be future-safe.
    return [elm for elm in style.map('Treeview', query_opt=option) if
        elm[:2] != ('!disabled', '!selected')]

style = ttk.Style()
style.map('Treeview', foreground=fixed_map('foreground'), background=fixed_map('background'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. I can confirm that this works with python 3.7.9 and Tkinter 8.6.9
BTW, I passed "style" as a parameter to fixed_map, to avoid accessing style as global variable.

Comment: Does this workaround make the colors tag-driven, as required by OP's question? I have a similar requirement (tag-dependent colors), but this workaround doesn't seem to involve tags

Comment: Thanks this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of things also with the help of my colleagues. We noticed that the tags only work up to the 3.7.2 Python version (not working on 3.7.3). This was tried in multiple computers and on both operating systems (Windows and Linux).

Answer (score 1):

In my app I use folloiwng approach:

```
self._my_tree.tag_configure('mygray', background='#DCDCDC')

for router in routers_list:
    self._my_tree.insert('', 'end', router['id'], text=str(router['id']),
                         values=(
                             name,
                             router['location'],
                             router['ip'],
                             router['model'],
                             router['phone_num'],
                             router['provider']
                         )
                         )

    self._my_tree.item(router['id'], tags='mygray')
```

Try using **tags** instead of **tag**

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I noticed though that you are using the tree.item() function while I am using tree.insert(). How are you inserting your data to the tree?

Comment: I'm using insert() as well. I think you lack of item iid, which is kind of item identifier as described in docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.insert
Please do take a look at the 3rd argument of my insert() use

Comment: I saw the docs and i also used the iid item but with no luck.. in my code the tree is populated with values even without the last line (tree.item())

Comment: Yes, but the last line (tree.item()) you probably need to decorate item with tags

Comment: Yes of course. I tried it also with tree.item() but it did not work. When I was using python 3.6 my code was working with just the insert line in which the tags were included as I mentioned in my question. The tags stopped working when I changed my environment to python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing colors to rgb? Try describing colors in format #RRGGBB where R G and B stands for amount of red green and blue colors ranging from 00 to FF in hexadecimal numbers

Comment: Tried it just now but with no effect.